# ¿Qué significa el valor register?

Tags: c

Tengo este código pero no sé lo que realmente significa y qué hace a la variable diferente de ser un `unsigned long` normal.

```
register unsigned long scan_local=0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [especificación](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> Una declaración de un identificador para un objeto con
>   especificador de clase de almacenamiento `register` sugiere que el acceso al
>   objeto sea lo más rápido posible. La medida en que tales
>   sugerencias son efectivas es definido por la implementación.

Es decir, es una sugerencia al compilador de que tu variable debe ser puesta en los registros para mayor rápidez de acceso, al ser sugerencia no está garantizado su cumplimiento.

Si se hace uso de este especificador no se puede utilizar el operador &, es decir no podes obtener la dirección de la variable (sea que se haya garantizado o no la ubicación en registro de la variable).